# all results matching keywords from result having second highest frequency

Tags: sql, nested, sql-like

I have a table `query` with 3 fields `(int)ID`, `(string)query` and `(int)freq`. I need to find out all queries which have matching keywords to the query with the second highest frequency. Here is what I tried,

```
select * from query 
where query like concat('%',(Select query from query 
where freq = (Select min(freq) from query
where freq in (Select freq from query order by freq desc limit 2))),'%');
```

I think the 'select query from' line isolates the query column and does not select any thing after. The last 2 select statements give the query with second highest frequency.
Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What database system, please? Without that it will be hard to give you a working answer. SQL Server, MySQL, postgre, Oracle, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, QUERY, FREQ
FROM
(
SELECT ID, QUERY, FREQ, ROW_NUMEBER() OVER(ORDER BY FREQ DESC) RN
FROM QUERY
) A
WHERE RN = 2
```

Comment: sorry my bad...Its SQL server